# Firebase invalid api key error in console ( Error (auth/invalid-api-key))

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables

I'm keeping the key value. The boot is giving me this error.

My code works fine if I don't use env variables, but I get this error when I use env variables.

.env.local code :

```
API_KEY=AIzaSyBPDUsNpEspYB-b_q8YUemjg8mp26BJCn0
AUTH_DOMAIN=phonesy-ad56a.firebaseapp.com
PROJECT_ID=phonesy-ad56a
STORAGE_BUCKET=phonesy-ad56a.appspot.com
MESSAGIBG_SENDER_ID=304429202901
APP_ID=1:304429202901:web:9b3c2fab35b3c4f36c115c
```

firebase init code :

```
apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGIBG_SENDER_ID,
appId: process.env.APP_ID,
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not expose your keys.
*Edit: Firebase configuration values are not sensitive.*

The problem is, you are using ".env.local". That is for local environment variables.

Rename your file to ".env", restart your server. Or create new file named ".env"

Comment: "do not expose your keys" Firebase configuration values are not your typical keys, so I recommend reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public. That said, I'd still typically not include them in my Stack Overflow questions and answer, but that is because they're not needed there.